# Entering text in Selenium Webdriver without sendkeys method

Tags: java, selenium

*I am trying to enter text using selenium JAVA and there is no input tag in the HTML .The sendkeys is not working .***IS there any other way we can enter text with out sendkeys option in selenium?**

**The HTML before entering the text is**

```
<pre class=" CodeMirror-line ">
  <span style="padding-right: 0.1px;">
   <span cm-text="">​</span>
 </span>
```

**And After entered the text "!echo  $PATH " the HTML is**

```
<pre class=" CodeMirror-line ">
 <span style="padding-right: 0.1px;">
  <span class="cm-operator">!</span>
  <span class="cm-variable">echo</span>  
  <span class="cm-error">$</span>
  <span class="cm-variable">PATH</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Which element did you try to send keys to? I would experiment with sending keys to different levels in the hierarchy. My first choice in this example without being able to inspect would probably be the `<pre ...>` element

Comment: Yes ,I am trying to send the keys to the element <pre ..>  .The xpath is //*[@id="container"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[5]/pre

Comment: When you say it's not working, do you mean it does nothing? Or does it throw an exception? That **xpath** is pretty verbose and might not be grabbing the element you expect. posting more of the relevant `html` in the question around that element might help.

Comment: When I use sendkeys method I am getting the exception org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it

Comment: Sounds like you're not sending keys to the right element. Have you tried sending keys to the `span` inside of the `pre`? Or the `div` that contains the `pre`?

Comment: Yes, I tried sending to the right element.The problem is there is no input tag for the element .I am trying to enter the text using javascript executer

Comment: There is no input tag similar to this one. <input id="username_input" type="username".

Comment: Even when there is an `input` tag, that's not necessary the correct `WebElement` to send text to. Just to confirm, you've tried sending text to both of these? `//*[@id="container"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div‌​[1]/div/div/div/div[‌​5]/pre/span` and `//*[@id="container"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div‌​[1]/div/div/div/div[‌​5]`?

Comment: Using the javascript executer can cause some freaky results, especially if you don't have a deep understanding of how the application code works. There should be a reasonable way to insert text with a `WebElement`, you most likely just need to find which element is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for your help @mrfreester .I am able to enter the text using Actions.    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys("TEXT").build().perform();